# Как выводить исключения в файл?

Tags: php

можно ли вывести исключения в файл не используя `try .. catch`?

Comment: Чтобы их вывести в файл, их сначала нужно перехватить, а в блоке catch сделать сохранение в файл через logger.

Answer (score 3):

Так лучше не делать.

Однако вот что есть:
https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/function.set-exception-handler.php

Пример из документации:

```
<?php
function exception_handler($exception) {
  echo "Неперехватываемое исключение: " , $exception->getMessage(), "\n";
}

set_exception_handler('exception_handler');

throw new Exception('Неперехватываемое исключение');
echo "Не выполнено\n";
?>
```